# Wishing everyone a Very Happy New Year 2021!

Tags: discussion

Last year is gone and was not that great for the world in general but I am grateful to be associated with this community. I love this community for being very active and encouraging and kind. It's been encouraging to see some really awesome queries posted and answers! So glad that with the current state of the world we are still together and come here to help each other.

Happy new year 2021 everyone and thank you for posting queries and taking the time to answer queries.

Let's hope we get to meet each other at some point soon.

Comment: Happy New Year Everyone :) (y)

Comment: Happy New Year's to you, too! I'm taking this year to work on my health, it's time to get serious with the world in disarray.

Comment: The statement i hear most is: I wish you a negative year 2021 (Covid related)